# scrapy: stop scraping before certain date

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a forum to a certain date, say 2018-01-01.

**Problem:**

Let's say a **forum page** is a page contains a list of posts without date. The problem is that date info of each post only exists in **post page** (which display actual content of that post). So I could not know the date before I actually scrape each post in the post list. I have to issue another request to scrape **post page** to get date info first then decide whether continue to follow **forum page**'s pagination.

I expect the spider to keep following **forum page**'s pagination until a post whose date is 2018-01-01 is scraped.

**Current approach:**

To stop after date 2018-01-01 is observed, I created a class property [`post_cont_dict`](https://github.com/spacegoing/sentiment_mqd/blob/2827969af42853d9aa13a63bdb2857ee2daf809c/guba_spiders/guba_spiders/spiders/guba_spider.py#L136) to determine if spider should continue following **forum page**'s pagination. When a date before 2018-01-01 is fetched from **post page**, the spider [will pop the key out](https://github.com/spacegoing/sentiment_mqd/blob/2827969af42853d9aa13a63bdb2857ee2daf809c/guba_spiders/guba_spiders/spiders/guba_spider.py#L270). Before a **post page request** to be issued, the spider first [check whether `post_cont_dict` has the key](https://github.com/spacegoing/sentiment_mqd/blob/2827969af42853d9aa13a63bdb2857ee2daf809c/guba_spiders/guba_spiders/spiders/guba_spider.py#L206)([also here](https://github.com/spacegoing/sentiment_mqd/blob/2827969af42853d9aa13a63bdb2857ee2daf809c/guba_spiders/guba_spiders/spiders/guba_spider.py#L225)) for **forum page**.

I also gave **post page** higher priority than **forum page** to avoid **forum page** requests issued later than **post page**. However, it didn't stop using my approach.

Here is my code https://github.com/spacegoing/sentiment_mqd/blob/test/guba_spiders/guba_spiders/spiders/guba_spider.py

Answer (score 0):

Does the forum offer the ability to sort by date? 
(You may need to use something like selenium or splash to interact with the page like this)
If the forum does support this feature, you could:
1.) Sort by Date
2.) Go through each forum post and keep track of the date
3.) When the date goes before 01-01-2018 you could raise a Close Spider exception:

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html#closespider

If you don't have the ability to sort by date, you need some other way of assuming or understanding what the date is before you enter a forum post. It's possible a date may be hidden in a data tag or something similar in the HTML.